# Pandas .stack() issue

Tags: python, pandas

I have been trying to use pandas to do a simple stack and it seems I am missing something.

I have a csv file in this format
[image]

I thought I would use stack to get this

[image]

The number of columns and number of items will vary

```
df = pd.read_csv("z-textsource.csv")
data_stacked = df.stack()
data_stacked.to_csv("z-textsource_stacked.csv")
```

However, when I run the code I get this

[image]

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

item column is not index now. Please try:

```py
df = pd.read_csv("z-textsource.csv", index_col=0)
```

And then the same code you use